# Grails 3.1.4 app deployment error

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment

I'm trying to deply a new grails 3.1.4 app to tomcat. I've just create the app with no change from the original, except in the build.gradle, where I added two lines:

```
dependencies {
    . . .
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}

. . .

war.archiveName = 'og.war'
```

I'm compiling using JVM 1.7.0.79 - 64 bits

It's loading to the server, and looking at the tomcat manager, and the og app is running, but when I try to open the app in my browser I got a 404 error page.

Any help is welcome

JP

Comment: I've being working in grails for 9 years now, nicely till 2.4 version - I'm not feeling happy with 3.x.x version, I even get problems in simple deployment and no new e-book for consulting

Comment: I'm compiling in windows 10, deployment to CentOS 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working now, original line is `compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"` . . . I just changed to `provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"`

Silly me, I added the new dependency when I should replace the original ! . . . I LOVE GRAILS

```
dependencies {
    . . .
    //compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    . . .
}

. . .
war.archiveName = 'og.war'
```